# EXCEL: Inserting multiple pictures in a single row, one at a time

Tags: image, insert

I am trying to use a macro-enabled button to insert pictures in the same Row. I use a spread sheet for work to capture facility issues, and I want to be able to add multiple pictures of these issues next to the cells which have a text explanation of the issue. Below is what I currently use, this just places one picture in Column G of the Row (Row 5 in this example)

```
Sub ChangeImage()
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Submit"
    .Title = "Select an image file"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
    .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
    .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
    .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
    .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
    .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

    If .Show = -1 Then
        Dim img As Object
        Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(.SelectedItems(1))

        'Scale image size
        'img.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.75, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        'img.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.75, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

        'Position Image
        img.Left = Range("G5").Left
        img.Top = Range("G5").Top


        'Set image sizes in points (72 point per inch)
        img.Width = 350
        img.Height = 350
    Else
        MsgBox ("Cancelled.")
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

I want to macro to be able to realize that pictures have already been added and to place the next picture starting at the RIGHT end of the last uploaded picture.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You should post the code you tried to use so far to do this.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, I thought I had included the code in the original question, is it not showing up?